# Diffeomorphic or isometric?!!

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I am a bigginer in differential geometry, i am confused about the following two notions:

Let $(S_1,d_1)$ and $(S_2,d_2)$ be two surfaces (endowed with  metrics $d_1,d_2$)

Can we talk about isometry between $S_1$ and $S_2$ without talking about metrics ? (because sometimes i find the sentence "two isometric surfaces"!! but they don t talk about metrics?? "

If $(S_1,d_1)$ and $(S_2,d_2)$ are "diffeomorphic" do this imply that they are isometric or the reverse is true ? What is stronger the notion  "diffeomorphic" or "isometric"

Answer (score 6):

If the surfaces are said to be isometric but the metrics are not explicitly mentioned, then they must be known from context.  For example, if these are given in
terms of embeddings in Euclidean space, the standard metric of that Euclidean space
is implied.

Diffeomorphic does not imply isometric. Examples are easy to construct.

Comment: Also relevant for OP to note that if $S_1\to S_2$ is a diffeomorphism and one of $S_1$ or $S_2$ has a metric, there is a unique metric in the other surface that makes this diffeomorphism become an isometry. +1

Comment: @Robert Israel Ok, thanks, and i also isometric doesn t imply differomorphic ? and if we have a diffeomorphism can we construct an isometry ? may be this is a silly question